# ImportError pysqlite2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I will ask

My PC：

- Ubuntu15.04(macbook)
- python2.7.9

Study of search engine programming

pysqlite Installed

```
>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
```

Why can not import　Please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Python 2.5, [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) became standard library module. ([What's new in Python 2.5 - sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#the-sqlite3-package))

So instead of using `pysqlite2`, use `sqlite3`:

```
>>> import sqlite3
```

OR

```
>>> import sqlite3 as sqlite
```